# Walking the tangle—How to get the parents?

Tags: tangle, tips

Looking at [Pseudocode to walk the tangle?](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/817/pseudocode-to-walk-the-tangle), in order to walk the tangle you look at the open tips and then you look for the parents. *getTips* gives you a list of all the open tips.  What API call is needed however to get the parents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **2** parents of a transactions are called *trunk transaction* and *branch transaction*.

You get them like this:
(It's python but the names and arguments in other libraries are very similar)

`getTips` returns a list of transaction hashes

```
tips = api.get_tips()['hashes']
```

---

Call `getTrytes` to fetch a transaction from its hash. (`tips[0]` for the first transaction in `tips`)

```
transaction_trytes = api.get_trytes([tips[0]])['trytes']
```

---

`Transaction.from_tryte_string` takes the trytes and *casts* them into a `Transaction`-object

```
transaction = Transaction.from_tryte_string(transaction_trytes[0])
```

---

To get the parents, use the properties of the transaction

```
trunkTransactionHash = transaction.trunk_transaction_hash()
branchTransactionHash = transaction.branch_transaction_hash()
```

---

Then you can call `getTrytes` again

```
trunkTransaction = api.get_trytes([trunkTransactionHash])
```

Comment: I've read the documentation about the lazy Tips and why you should use these algorithms in order to get the "best" Tips. But I have a question: is possible to choose by myself what tips refer to? And is possible to refer to a parent transaction that is not a Tip?